# Is language objective or subjective?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Can somebody explain why the word “why” for example is objectively the word “why” and spelt as such in the English language when it was formed through subjective experience?

Comment: Language is "objective" because people use it to communicate with each other, and get corrected when "subjective experience" leads to using words in ways others do not recognize. Since everything people learn is "formed through subjective experience" that is not very useful for distinguishing subjective and objective.

Comment: There is no objectivity, only reified intersubjectivity. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79366/why-ask-why-and-its-scions/79438#79438

Comment: The concept of "intersubjectivity" already presupposes the objective existence of other people.  This is the fallacy of the stolen concept, where you are using objectivity to deny objectivity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea#Indirectly_self-denying_statements_or_%22fallacy_of_the_stolen_concept%22